# How do you programmatically set ViewPager tabs from inside a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a `database` that provides an array of `Strings`, accessed from within a `Fragment`. I want these Strings to go back to the activity attached to the Fragment and set the titles of the tabs in a `ViewPager`. How can I do this?

This is how I want to do it:

> Database String[] → Fragment → Attached activity's ViewPager → New
>   tabs

Edit: Here is my entire Activity and PagerAdapter [code](https://pastebin.com/VtgswHTU).

Here is my Fragment [code](https://pastebin.com/KS8gTnFb)

Comment: make a custom `interface,` and attach it to the `fragment`, then `implement` that interface in `activity` you will receive `callbacks`

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: please check the answer below

Comment: Please post your Activity, ViewPagerAdapter and Fragment code.

Comment: Done, check the post.

Comment: Why are you observing the list in `PlaceholderFragment`? Is your menu items and sub menu items updating frequently or dynamically? You can just call the database query and fetch data for one time if your menu and sub menu items are not update frequently.

Comment: I do it because the database return type is of `LiveData<String[]>`. If I don't use LiveData then the app will crash because I'm trying to do database queries on the main thread and apparently I shouldn't do that because it could lock the UI for a long time. Also because I'll lose marks if I perform database queries on the main thread.

Comment: To get data from database without executing query on main thread, you have to use AsyncTask. Are you getting correct list in `Log.d(TAG, "Received " + strings[i]);'?

Comment: No, that list is empty. How would I use AsyncTask?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179403/discussion-between-viraj-patel-and-siku-m).

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have array of `Strings` and you want to send them to your `activity` from `Fragment`, make an `interface` like

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
CustomStrings mCallback;

// Container Activity must implement this interface
public interface CustomStrings {
    public void onStringRecieved(String[] stringss);
} 


@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (CustomStrings) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnHeadlineSelectedListener");
    }
}
```

And then simple use this when you need to send data

```
mCallback.onStringRecieved(yourStrings); //your data here
```

And then in your activity implement it

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
    implements MyFragment.CustomStrings{
...

public void onStringRecieved(String[] stringss) {

    // Do something here to use these strings
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+strings, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Hope this solves your problem, for more information refer [this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating)

Comment: I don't receive the `String`s in the activity, I retrieve them from within the `Fragment`.

Comment: `mCallback.onStringRecieved(yourStrings);` use this where u are receiving strings in fragment, and you will have them in activity's `onStringRecieved` method

Comment: Okay, let me try this.

Comment: Done, check the post.

Comment: add a `Toast.makeText(getContext(), ""+strings, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` in activity onReceive

Comment: Output is `[Ljava.lang.String;@[randomly generated UID i think?]`

Comment: @SikuM. this means code is working fine, its just that you are not able to use it correctly, for the starter just send the one string only, then send list of strings. and please accept my answer and upvote it as it solved your main problem